# Can upgrading the timeout for my proxy pass in Nginx and Gunicorn cause any problems?

Tags: nginx, ubuntu-16.04, gunicorn

I'm going to add these configuration:

```
proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
proxy_read_timeout 300s;
```

and for Gunicorn:

```
gunicorn_django -D -b 127.0.0.1:8901 --workers=5 --pid=/var/webapp/campus.pid --settings=settings.production --timeout 300 --pythonpath=/var/webapp/campus/
```

Can this cause any problems I do not know about?

([Additional context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11704004/getting-error-502-when-processing-an-excel-file-with-many-rows))

Answer (score 0):

Per nginx document you can't give this much big timeout. Also it depend on tcp defaults to maintain connections.

```
Syntax: proxy_connect_timeout time;
Default:    
proxy_connect_timeout 60s;
```

Context:    http, server, location
Defines a timeout for establishing a connection with a proxied server. It should be noted that this timeout cannot usually exceed 75 seconds.
https://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_proxy_module.html#proxy_connect_timeout

Adverse effect will be connections exhausted, connections leak etc.